# Error while running Terraform provisioner "local-exec"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, null, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I am executing this code:

```
resource "null_resource" "enable-usage-plan" {
  triggers = {
    usage_plan_id = "cd8lab"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws apigateway update-usage-plan --usage-plan-id cd8lab --patch-operations op ="add",path="/apiStages",value="7tdnnlppg1:poc""
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error: Missing newline after argument
> on main.tf line 9, in resource "null_resource" "enable-usage-plan":
> 9:     command = "aws apigateway update-usage-plan --usage-plan-id sx8lzu --patch-operations op="add",path="/apiStages",value="7tdnnlppg1:poc"".
> An argument definition must end with a newline.

When I ran he same command on AWS CLI the command worked fine.

Is there any thing I need to change in the command to execute in the `local exec`?

Comment: Please put the error in a code block, explain what you tried to fix this error, and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [escape](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences) your string:

```
resource "null_resource" "enable-usage-plan" {

  triggers = {
    usage_plan_id = "cd8lab"
  }


  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws apigateway update-usage-plan --usage-plan-id cd8lab --patch-operations op=\"add\",path=\"/apiStages\",value=\"7tdnnlppg1:poc\""
  }
}
```

Comment: still getting error: │ Error: local-exec provisioner error
│
│   with null_resource.enable-usage-plan,
│   on main.tf line 8, in resource "null_resource" "enable-usage-plan":
│    8:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│
│ Error running command 'aws apigateway update-usage-plan --usage-plan-id cd8lab --patch-operations op    
│ ="add",path="/apiStages",value="7tdnnlppg1:poc"': exit status 252. Output:
│ Error parsing parameter '--patch-operations': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
│ op
│   ^

Comment: hi Marcin, Still i see the above error.

Comment: I think there might be an extra space after `op`.

Comment: @DharmaraoKatkuri This is new error, because the issue you reported has been fixed. You have to double check your command and what arguments it takes. Also you have space in `op =`.